# Insert random row to table and then delete

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I've got two tables: tableA and tableB. I would like to insert random row from tableA to tableB and then delete this row from tableA. How can i do it? Is it possible at all? Below is my insert code but i dont know how to delete this row.

```
INSERT INTO tableB
SELECT * FROM tableA ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Is there a primary key in the tableA and tableB?

Comment: No, it's simple tables without any primary key.

Comment: They should have a primary key. Without it how can you specify which row to update or delete?

Comment: Ok, i created a new tableA with primarykeys connected to elementA and elementB of tableA.

Comment: Doe this mean that the value of the column elementA from TbleA will be inserted in the column elementB of the TableB?

Comment: I am just start learning Sqlite and i'm little bit confused:) I would like the situation when value of the column elementA from TableA will be inserted in the column elementA of the TableB. BTW. your previous solution(idRow) works perfectly well when there are no random elements.

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`rowid`](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html):

```
DELETE from tableA
WHERE elementA = (
  SELECT elementA from tableB
  WHERE rowid = (SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM tableB) 
)
```

Provided that elementA is unique in both tables, if this is executed after your INSERT statement it will find elementA from the inserted row and delete the row from TableA with that elementA.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I must delete row from tableA not from tableB. Your solution didn't work properly with my problem(delete item with max ID ). I must delete exactly this random row from tableA.

Comment: This is perfect solution:), Thank you for your help